# Como realizar una expresión regular para validar un C.I. Boliviano?

Tags: javascript, regex

Cedula de Identidad(C.I.).
Necesito validar un C.I. boliviano para lo cual quise utilizar expresiones regulares pero no puedo conseguir mi cometido, ya que apenas lo estoy aprendiendo.

Ejemplos de C.I. validos:

```
8788273
53828
10399283
8788273 1K
53828-3I
10399283 9A
```

En algún momento de la historia los C.I. se duplicaron y le agregaron un espacio o guión seguidos numero junto a una letra para solucionarlo, los cuales son opcionales.

Tengo esto pero no me funciona:

```js
function verificar(){
 m=document.getElementById("prueba").value;
 var r=new RegExp("^\d{5,10}(\\s|[-])\d{1}[A-Z]{1})$");
 if(r.test(m))
 alert("el ci es correcto"); 
  else 
    alert("el ci NO es correcto"); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="prueba">
<button onClick="verificar()">Probar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas comillas Javascript lo interpreta como un texto, no como una expresión regular, lo correcto es usar / al inicio y final de tu expresión.

Para indicar que es un espacio lo que esperas necesitas usar el parámetro `\s`, si usas doble `\\` estás escapeando el backslash, por lo que el sistema espera que ingreses un `\s` y no un espacio.

También tienes que pensar en que el complemento para ci duplicados es opcional, por tanto debes encerrar esa parte en `(expresion)?`

Por todo lo demás está bien tu expresión regular.

```js
function verificar(){
 m=document.getElementById("prueba").value;
 var r=new RegExp(/^\d{5,10}((\s|[-])\d{1}[A-Z]{1})?$/);
 if(r.test(m))
 alert("el ci es correcto"); 
  else 
    alert("el ci NO es correcto"); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="prueba">
<button onClick="verificar()">Probar</button>
```

También podrías simplificarlo un poco:

```
/^\d{5,10}([\s-]\d[A-Z])?$/
```

Comment: Genial, gracias por tu tiempo.